# concatenation in hive based on sequence number

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, concatenation

I am not able to concatenate a field based on the sequence number for a specific id.

```
id    field1   seq number
1       a            1
1       b            3
1       c            2
2       d            1
2       e            2
```

expected result

```
id       field1   
1        acb   
2        de
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collect_list` to aggregate strings into array and `concat_ws` to concatenate array. `collect_list` is using `ArrayList`, it keeps data in the order it was inserted. Use `sort` in the subquery before `collect_list` to sort values inserted in the array.

Test in Hive:

```
with s as --this is your data
(select stack(5,
              1,'a',1,
              1,'b',3,
              1,'c',2,
              2,'d',1,
              2,'e',2) as (id,field1,seq_number)
)

select s.id, concat_ws('',collect_list(s.field1)) as field1    
from 
 (select s.id, s.field1, s.seq_number from s sort by s.seq_number) s --SORT is here
group by s.id;
```

Result:

```
OK
id      field1
1       acb
2       de
```

Comment: thanks a lot. can collect list be also used in impala? or is there a substitute for the same

Comment: @HimanshuGarg No, unfortunately, Impala has no the same collect_list function, Impala has group_concat. Read this Jira about ordering and version information: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-1458, Also this is group_concat docs: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_group_concat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursive function to get the desired result. But remember if the dimension of your data is high, then try another approach, cause in some Languages (i.e, SQL Server) recursive function's nesting level isn't more than 32!

```
        Create Function function(@ID Int, @i Int)
        Returns VarChar(8000)
        As
        Begin
        -- variables for storing data and return values
            Declare @string VarChar(8000), @temp VarChar(8000)
            Select @i = @i-1, @string = Field1 + ', ' From dbo.Errors E1 Where Id = @ID And
            @i = (Select Count(*) From dbo.Errors E2 Where E2.Id = E1.Id and E2.Field1 <= E1.Field1);

            If @i > 0 
            Begin
                Exec @temp = dbo.function@ID, @i;
                -- concatenate values every time the funtion returns
                Set @string = @temp + @string
            End
               -- return the resulatant data;
            Return @r;                              
        End
        Go
```

And your function needs to be invokded by following:

```
     Select ID, dbo.function(ID, Count(Field1)) From dbo.Errors Group By ID;
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string)

```
SELECT ID ,(Select SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ',' + FIELD1 AS 'data()'
    FROM TABLE WHERE ID = table.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 2 , 9999)) As FIELD1 
FROM table 
GROUP BY ID
```